# How can I pre-fill a text input when I open the app?

Tags: python, kivy

I heard that I can pre-fill text input when I open an app with `text` property, but I am unsure how to do it without it being a class method. Does anyone know a way I could do this?

Python:

```
class LoginScreen(Screen):                          #This screen is 
    has_the_user_already_saved_login = open('saved/checkbox.txt', 'r')
    user_previous_login = open('saved/rLD.txt', 'r')

    if has_the_user_already_saved_login.read() == 'True':
        has_the_user_already_saved_login.close()
        print('User has selected the checkbox in the past')
        s_email, s_password = user_previous_login.read().strip().split(';')
        user_previous_login.close()
        print(s_email)
        print(s_password)
        manager.root.ids.email.text = s_email
        manager.root.ids.psswrd = s_password

    def loginBtn(self):
        login_email = self.email.text
        login_password = self.password.text
```

Kivy:

```
TextInput:
    id: email

TextInput:
    id: psswrd
```

I've edited this post for clarity. This is my actual code (as seen above) with the non important lines removed. I want the `if` statement in the class to take the `s_email` and `s_password` and fill the two text inputs with them. As you can see I tried various approaches such as using `root` and `manager`, but so far I haven't found a solution. Currently the text inputs' data is collected in the loginBtn section action a user presses a button. How can I fill the text inputs with these new variables?

Comment: Your `if` statement is not within a method, so it is executed when the `LoginScreen` class is loaded. That happens before the `App` is even started.

Comment: Exactly. This code checks to see if a user has selected a "remember login" button in the past by reading a text file. Before the app even starts I want the text inputs to be filled with their login data, ie. email and password.

Comment: Consider putting that code in an `on_enter()` method of your `LoginScreen`. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen).

Comment: This is exactly the kind of method that I needed, thank you! However, I see online that the syntax I should be using to fill the text inputs is ```self.root.ids.email.text = s_email```, but that only shows errors saying ``` AttributeError: LoginScreen object has no attribute root```. What should I do?

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, I cannot answer that. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wherever you define the `TextInput`, you can define its `text` attribute. If it is in `py`:

```
TextInput(text='Abba Dabba Doo')
```

If it is in `kv`:

```
TextInput:
    text: 'Abba Dabba Doo'
```

Comment: This would normally work, however, the text that needs to be there is read off a text file, so it is constantly changing.

Comment: Then do it in python after reading it from the file: `ti_instance.text = some_string`.

Comment: I'm still a little confused. Would the syntax look like: ```self.root.ids.email.text = some_string```? Because I keep getting errors saying either ```self``` or ```root``` is not defined (I know why ```self``` is not working, because it is not within a class method)

Comment: Cannot determine without seeing a [mcve].

Comment: I've edited my post to include my code. I still do not understand the exact syntax I need to use.